# Google Cloud Storage with double slashes in the file path

Tags: google-cloud-storage

This issue cost me some time as some files seemed to disappear. I'm not sure if this is the correct behavior when (in my case inadvertently) a file with double slashes is added to Google Cloud Storage.

This is how to recreate the issue:

```
$ vi test (create a simple file)
$ gsutil cp test gs://xxxxx.appspot.com/test/doubleslash//test
Copying file://test [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
Uploading   gs://xxxxx.appspot.com/test/doubleslash//test:     15 B/15 B
// attempting gsutil ls command with one slash ... only the folder shows    
$ gsutil ls -al gs://xxxxx.appspot.com/test/doubleslash/
                                 gs://xxxxx.appspot.com/test/doubleslash//
// attempting gsutil ls command with two slashes ... only the folder shows    
$ gsutil ls -al gs://xxxxx.appspot.com/test/doubleslash//
                                 gs://xxxxx.appspot.com/test/doubleslash//
$
```

Note: the "test" file isn't shown. However, supplying the full file path, it does appear:

```
$ gsutil ls -al gs://xxxxx.appspot.com/test/doubleslash//test
        15  2015-11-27T17:21:24Z  gs://xxxxx.appspot.com/test/doubleslash//test#1448644884041000  metageneration=1
TOTAL: 1 objects, 15 bytes (15 B)
```

Finally, the really odd part is that when adding a file into the single slash folder (called testInside), then doing "gsutil ls" command with the *double slash*, the file in the *single slash* folder appears, but the one in the double slash folder does not:

```
$ gsutil cp test gs://xxxxx.appspot.com/test/doubleslash/testInside
Copying file://test [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
Uploading   …/xxxxx.appspot.com/test/doubleslash/testInside: 15 B/15 B  
$ gsutil ls -al gs://xxxxx.appspot.com/test/doubleslash//
                                     gs://xxxxx.appspot.com/test/doubleslash//
            15  2015-11-27T20:14:42Z  gs://xxxxx.appspot.com/test/doubleslash/testInside#1448655282555000  metageneration=1
    TOTAL: 1 objects, 15 bytes (15 B)
```

Now, via the app when listing the folder, the files in the double slash folder *do* appear along with any files in the single slash folder (when specifying one slash):

build.gradle:

```
compile ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev54-1.21.0')
```

Java code:

```
Objects response = storageService.objects()
                       .list(“xxxxx.appspot.com")
                       .setPrefix(“test/doubleslash/").execute();
```

I cannot determine the reasoning for the file inside the double slash folder appearing from code, but not from the gsutil command line. comments?

Comment: Hi Craig. Is there a question more than "comments"? Because if the only intent you had about this question is to expose the behavior, google groups might be more suited for that https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine. Stack is really for questions and answers, not for posts highlighting things like this. If you believe this is a bug and want to see what can be fixes about it, the Issue Tracker would be the appropriate site for that : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/   Cheers!

Comment: I believe it's a bug, but if Google wants to explain why it's works as designed, then I'd be open to that explanation.

Comment: Both the (possible) explanation, report, and fixing of that bug should be on our issue tracker. As much as we advertise Stack as a place where we support customers, it isn't appropriate for every topic out there. I'd suggest taking it to the Issue Tracker I linked previously where either myself or someone from the team will pick it up to see what can be done :).  Cheers!

Comment: For anyone finding this post, it seems like this behavior/bug is still present four years later.

Comment: I believe at the end of December of 2021 the issue is still in place as cloud-builders-community/cache/ builder is unable to find the cache object after creating it.